# Retrieve SVG source by POST and replace current SVG

Tags: php, jquery, html, svg

The SVG-code is rendered directly inside the HTML (`<div id="svg">svg-code-here</div>`).
The SVG-code needs to be replaced when the user clicks on a value of a `<select name="svg-changer">`.

Stripped example of the JS-script & PHP-code:

```
$('#svg-changer').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        url: "/update",
        data: {"k": 'svg', "v": this.value},
        success: function(resp) {
            $("#svg").html(resp);
        }
    });
});
```

The SVG-code is being retrieved using PHP (`/update`):

```
<?php
exit(json_encode('resp' => file_get_contents('path/to/image.svg')));
```

The response is visible inside the console, but I'm unable to replace the current HTML.
When using non-SVG code, the `#svg` content is being replaced without any issue.

Should the SVG-code be encoded for jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: since svg is not html but xml, the .html() function of jQuery might not be what you want to use. For example is jQuery not case sensitive which some svg tags require. Maybe try .text() or some js-svg rendering library.

Comment: Try `$("#svg").get(0).innerHTML = resp;` instead.

Comment: Thanks @user3154108 and @paul-lebeau; I did try using .text(), but for reason it didn't rendered the SVG proper when using it. At the moment it seems replacing the HTML works just fine, maybe because it's being corrected by Inkscape when saving as an 'Optimized SVG'? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code is returning an JSON object and you're not using the response that way in your ajax call. You can just use

```
exit(file_get_contents('path/to/image.svg'));
```

or set `dataType` as `json` in jQuery call and use `resp.resp`, but that wouldn't make much sense, right? It would result in something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    url: "/update",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {"k": 'svg', "v": this.value},
    success: function(response) { // You can name it wherever you want, but...
        $("#svg").html(response.resp); // You have to access .resp attribute, set in PHP
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.